# MS Access: Subform only displays first entry. Continuous Form follow-up question

Tags: ms-access

I am new to MS Access and Database creation in general. Currently I am working on a simple employee database that can view an employee's information and can show their current (and previous) projects and training courses within the company. Below is a snapshot of my Relationship Chart.

[image]

My question is twofold,

1.) I am working on a subform that shows the projects currently and previously taken by an employee (The Project Status table shows either Current or Previous status. More can be added later on). When I create the subform however, it only shows the first entry, regardless if the employee has multiple entries. Below is a picture of the form.
[image]

2.) Is there a more ideal way to create a form that gets sources from 2 different queries than getting a mainform and putting a subform inside? As you can see I am getting the entries on the form depending on the combo box selection. Furthermore, is there any way to make a dynamic subform that can expand depending on the number of entries it outputs? My gripe with using a Continuous form is that it also shows the blank "next" entry.

Many thanks.